# default is not a function React Type error

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, speech-to-text

Hi guys i want to make speech to text in React component. But when i run it I get this error:
`react_speech_recognition__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function`
Can someone show me what to do?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition from 'react-speech-recognition'

class Mic extends Component {
  render() {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props

    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
      return null
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
        <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        <p>{transcript}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SpeechRecognition(Mic)
```

In app.js i run it like this (if this is necessary):

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Container from './components/container/Container';
import Database from './components/database/Database';
import Mic from './components/mic/Mic';
import Test from './components/test/Test';

function App() {
  return (
    <Mic/>
    //<Test/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this line `SpeechRecognition(Mic)` . The Error states that the default export from your module is not a function which means that `SpeechRecognition` is not a function so you cannot call it .

change your code as

```
import React from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition'

const Mic = () => {
  const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition()

  if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
      <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
      <p>{transcript}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Mic
```

Looks like you have installed the latest version, but trying to use it in old way.

Please take a look at this [Migration Guide](https://github.com/JamesBrill/react-speech-recognition/blob/HEAD/docs/V3-MIGRATION.md)